# Handling realm query in async task

Tags: android, realm

I am using an async class to do some Realm Query and as per the query result saving it into another realm object but it gives me error i.e 
Realm access from incorrect thread

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

     DBTest test= RealmManager.getInstance().getRealmInstance().where(DBTest.class).contains("vendor", "rocky", Case.INSENSITIVE).findFirst();

    if (cat != null){ currentCategory = new Category(cat.getID,"Misc");

    }
         RealmManager.getInstance().save(new Cateogry(currentCategory.getType, "class A"), Cateogry.class);


}
```

I tried Realm async query also but its giving me same error ,Can some body explain why its happening ?

Comment: Please take a look at Realm's threading document https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#threading . `Realm`, `RealmObject` and `RealmResults` cannot be accessed across thread.  Your `RealmManager.getInstance()` is singleton, right? So it might create Realm instance in the UI thread and use it in the background thread.

Comment: @beeender Yes its a singleton class, The method you see doInBackground is actually a asynctask class . What I wanted to do is in doInBackground is query the Realm ,get the value from query ,In my case a  DBTest object and then save it into Realm. Is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: You can just use `Realm.getInstance()` to get/create a Realm for the background thread, and use that Realm instead. https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/threadExample here is example for helping you with threading related use cases.